# How to resolve all google play-services dependencies with gradle?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

## Situation

Today, after touching nothing of the project, my gradle yelled at me and wouldn't compile the project. It failed to resolve `firebase-iid`, `firebase-common`, `play-services-analytics-impl`, `play-services-auth-api-phone`, and `play-services-auth-base`. So quite a mess after the weekend.

So I checked the versions of the different APIs, and upgraded the ones that needed upgrading, found out that Google had added a mandatory dependency to `firebase-core`, added it, then upgraded my `google-services` plugin, and even added a `play-services-base` dependency. I also upgraded `firebase-messaging` to version 17.0.0, and `crashlytics` to version 2.9.3.

But still, the build doesn't compile, with this error message:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2], [15.0.4,15.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

## Gradle Files

Here is my Gradle file (showing dependencies part only), after my attempted fixes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':otherlibrary')
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.darwinsys/hirondelle-date4j
    implementation group: 'com.darwinsys', name: 'hirondelle-date4j', version: '1.5.1'
    // For RxAndroid and RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
// (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases for latest 2.x.x version)
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'

    // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'

    // CSV with outputstream writer
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1'

    // Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    debugImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my project-wide gradle contain these lines:

```
...
repositories {
    maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       name 'Google'
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
...
```

## Official solution doesn't work

I already tried to fix the version number of multiple libraries according to the [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), which is more or less the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200775/android-studio-error-the-library-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measuremen/50211565).
As you can read in the official documentation link, as of May 2nd, 2018, they offered a way to fix this kind of issue, but the numbers of the versions in question are not the same, and I already tried the given fix (with some downgrades now), to no avail.

> **Official documentation:** 
>   If your app has a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0 as well as any of the following libraries:
>
> ```
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager
> com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crash
> com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links
> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging
> ```
>
> You will need to update the version of the latter dependency to
>   15.0.2. This addresses the issue where version 3.3.0 of the Google Services Gradle plugin reports: The library
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0],
>   [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2...

**So how can I resolve these conflicts of versions in order for my build to compile once again correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a day lost in this issue, I found out that the latest version of `play-services-analytics` is **not** the one they have published in [their website](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). It is `16.0.0` and not `15.0.2`.

Android Studio told that to a colleague as a warning, but mine was unconcerned about it. So here it is, the line that changes everything:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
```

Comment: The only "workaround" I found so far to detect new undocumented versions is to use "+" as a version number and sync/build the project once. Afterwards you can revert the change and Android Studio will complain that there are (maybe) newer versions in the local cache...

Comment: you can always check the google repository for the latest versions https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my build.gradle (application version) and it worked:

```
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

*(Keep in mind that this is just to disable the version check, it does not actually fix anything)*

Comment: Please can you specify where did you add it ?

Comment: @DrissBounouar I added it to the bottom of build.gradle on application level (not project level)

Comment: Actually, it's only a temporary solution. You may run into some problems with your app later and then you'll have to correct the version

Comment: @DevanshMaurya Obviously as it just disables a check, but it does the job for now. I have dont know how to set all the correct versions, since they are bundled inside other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reverting back to an old build, and it seemed to work, what i found was that the `gradle-wrapper.properties` was using and older version (4.5) instead of the 4.6 i had in the newer project. Changing this as well as reverting to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha08'` from alpha15 seemed to do the trick. I think you can use the alpha 15 if you like, but to be sure you can use the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`.
Along with all these changes the `firebase-core` and the `google-gms-services` should be set to version 16.0.0.

Comment: I upgraded my `gradle-wrapper.properties` to 4.6-all or 4.7-all, and I already had the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`, but the error is still here...  
I'm currently trying to exclude the `play-services-measurement-base` from all dependencies and to import it directly. For now, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately google play service has been stopped 
This widows msg are generated &never run any google service performs