# Firebase - Gradle failed on build - com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base

Tags: react-native, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

Recently I updated all my versions in the build.gradle file and still the build fails every time.

I get this error message

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I have tried all of the solutions suggested in other posts like:

- [Gradle sync fails - play-services-measurement-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569501/gradle-sync-fails-play-services-measurement-base)
- [Android Studio Error The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200775/android-studio-error-the-library-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measuremen)
- [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Unfortunately, nothing worked, and I am desperate.

I am using react native with Firebase and Firestore.

Comment: What does `./gradlew :app:dependencies` say?

Answer (score 0):

Got this same error and have been stuck on it all week. I had this problem with another library and ended up having to manually change the version of the conflicting library. In that case, `./gradlew :app:dependencies` was able to highlight which package it was. In this case, it does not.

All I'm seeing in the analyze depenedencies call is

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.1.1] -> 16.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0 (*)
```

which hints that its resolving at 16.0.1 which what I intended..

```
compile ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1") {
    force = true
}
```

Here's my error:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.1,16.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

Comment: `force = true` is deprecated. Use `MutableVersionConstraint#strictly(String)` instead